# jquery hide a div that contains flash without resetting it

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, html

Greetings,
I have written a modal using jquery UI and it appears at the front of a flash movie thus the html inside the modal becomes corrupt, I tried to hide the movie right before modal gets triggered and reappears after closing the modal, works well but each .hide() and .show() the flash movie gets resetted while all I want is to hide (without removing the movie) and displaying it once it is triggered to .show that modal div.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tested in FF/linux, FF/WinXp, IE/WinXp, Safari/WinXp:

- put your flash container DIV into a new *DIV with overflow:hidden*.

basic:

- to hide flash-div: $('#id_div_with_swf').css("left","-2000px");
- to show flash-div: $('#id_div_with_swf').css("left","0px");

or, show and hide with animation effects:

- to hide flash-div: $('#id_div_with_swf').animate({ left: "-2000px"},1000);
- to show flash-div: $('#id_div_with_swf').animate({ left: "0"},1000);

html example:

```
<div style="width:200px; height:100px; overflow:hidden;">
<div id="id_div_with_swf" style="width:200px; height:100px; position:relative; left:0px; top:0px;">
<!-- flash here -->
</div>
</div>
```

---

you can't get a cross-browser working solution with .css('visibility', 'visible'/'hidden')

Comment: Wouldn't this toggle display of a huge horizontal scrollbar in the browser?

Answer (score 8):

Working solution:

Use `$('#myvideo').css('visibility', 'hidden')` to hide and
    `$('#myvideo').css('visibility', 'visible')` to show the div containing the video.

Just tested it with firebug.

*EDIT*:
Please note, this is different from `.hide()` and `.show()`, as they use the `display` css, instead of `visibility`.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps move the movie div off the screen. Set it's Left position to be -1000 or something like that?

Then replace when the other div has disappeared?