# Flash object's methods unavailable after hiding

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, dom

I'm developing in Javascript with jQuery, using Chrome 23.0.1271.97. I have a Flex `<object>`, The HTML is as follows:

```
<div id="chartdiv" style="display:none;">
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="barchart" data="barchart.swf" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
<param name="movie" value="barchart.swf" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
</object>
</div>
```

The div is normally hidden, but the object is initialized onLoad anyway. However, when the app is loaded, then this div is shown and everything works. The problem is if it is, from that point, hidden again (just hidden, like `$div.hide()`, not uninitialized) then later reshown, I cannot access the Flex objects methods.

I get `Object #<HTMLObjectElement> has no method 'blah'`. It appears to have been modified, but I'm not sure what's causing it.

So what's changing? Good question. On a successful load, the object works and looks like this in the console:

```
<object type=​"application/​x-shockwave-flash" id=​"barchart" data=​"barchart.swf" style=​"width:​100%;​height:​100%;​">​
</object>​
```

The object looks like this on an unsuccessful attempt (after showing, hiding, and coming back):

```
<object type=​"application/​x-shockwave-flash" id=​"barchart" data=​"barchart.swf" style=​"width:​100%;​height:​100%;​">​
<param name=​"movie" value=​"barchart.swf">​
<param name=​"quality" value=​"high">​
<param name=​"allowScriptAccess" value=​"always">​
<param name=​"wmode" value=​"transparent">​
</object>​
```

Which makes me thing maybe I am looking in the wrong place. I've stepped through my front end Javascript code, there don't seem to be any calls to modify the object, other than hiding it via jQuery. I'm told the Flex object doesn't know if it's shown or not. Before I ask to see the code I want to be sure I'm on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been searching and it seems the [flash object gets reset when hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825792/jquery-hide-a-div-that-contains-flash-without-resetting-it).

So my solution is to test the jQuery/DOM object, and to see if the method is defined:

```
function isFlashWorking()
{
    return ($chart && chart.blah)
}
```

Where `blah` is a known method in the object.

Answer (score 1):

This is know issue. One of the best solutions if you don't want to reset your flash object is just to set its size to few pixels which will be invisible to user but 'visible' for browser.

Answer (score 1):

Shift it off screen so the object is still viable.
See example in this article:
[jquery hide a div that contains flash without resetting it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825792/jquery-hide-a-div-that-contains-flash-without-resetting-it)