# Open jquery ui dialog from flex/flash

Tags: jquery, html, flash, apache-flex

I need to open html pop-up to show some d3.js visualization in flex application that runs in browser.

I am planning to use jquery UI dialog for this purpose, but the question is how can I trigger modal box from flex application?

The only solution that came to my mind is to use websocket connection to trigger jquery modal dialog from server-side and it's my last resort. Is there a better way to trigger jquery modal from flash?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer:

```
var jscommand:String = "$('#modalGraph').dialog('open');";
var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("javascript:" + jscommand + " void(0);");
navigateToURL(url, "_self");
```

Comment: If you want it to be a popup you should use navigateToURL(url, "_blank");

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the url of the browser and causing a post back just hide the  the flex app by calling out to javascript using ExternalInterface:

```
ExternalInterface.call("yourJavascriptFunctionNameToHideTheFlexApp()");
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

Hide the flex application:
[jquery hide a div that contains flash without resetting it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825792/jquery-hide-a-div-that-contains-flash-without-resetting-it)

Then show your div with the d3 visualization.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Clintm. I used the solution below and it does not change url of the browser and works just as fine. And I used wmode transparency to put html on top of flash.

Can you tell me why your solution would be better than the one I implemented?